choose $2$ people such that they both play with $2l$ people
In a room has $n$ people. Prove that:
a) If there is one people who play with $2k+1$ people in that room. We can choose $2$ people such that they both play with $2l$ people in that room with $k,l$ are positive integers.
b) If there are some people who play with a number of people which is odd. We can choose $2$ people like a)
By solving a), I try to show the existence of that people
Put $G(V,E)$ is a graph which has $|V| = n$ then there exists a $v$ such that $d(v) \not \vdots 2$
Then we will work on the graph $G(V',E')$ which $|V| = 2k+1$ contain all the people who play with the one who play with $2k+1$ people
Then in that graph which has odd $v$ must exist $v'$ such that $d(v') \vdots 2$
But from here, I can't show there is another people with the same condition and they play with same number of people which is even
Can anyone continue from here? Thank you a lots

It's not quite clear what (a) means, but my most natural interpretation makes it false if the graph is $K_{1,n-1}$ for even $n$: one person plays with everyone else, and they don't play each other. Then the center person plays $2k+1$ people for $k = \frac n2 - 1$, and nobody plays $2l$ people for any $l$.

It means that in a room has $n$ people and exist one people who play with a number of people and that number is odd. Then we have to prove...

One person, not one people. Most of my confusion is hidden away behind the ... in your comment, but perhaps the useful thing for you to say is whether or not my counterexample actually is a counterexample - and if not, why not.

sorry for my poor english. There exist one person who plays with a number of people which is odd. Then we have to prove that we can choose $2$ people from $n$ people which both play with $2l$ people

Right, and I'm saying that in the example I gave, we can't prove that, because it's not true.

I don't know if this help you: In the classroom, there is a student who is close to an odd number of friends. Prove that in the class there are two students who are close friends with an even number of friends in the class
Here is the original link: https://mathscope.org/showthread.php?t=18866

That version doesn't say that the two even numbers have to be the same. But it's still false, because there are graphs on any number of vertices where all the degrees, or all but one of the degrees, are odd.

Can you fix the problem so it can be true? Thank you
